# how to merge two tables to get the last new rows from table 2 and the rest from table 1

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i have a problem with joins on two tables into an oracle database, and i can't do that it works.
if you see on the image you can two options.

[image]

i execute this query:

```
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, f.price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new <> g.id_hist)
union
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, g.new_price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
```

for option/case 1 it **works**!

but for option/case 2 this query return empty, no rows. and the idea is that must resturn all row from historical information.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `NOT IN` to find the records unmatched with new_table `g`, and gather with the records retrieved by `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, f.price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
WHERE f.id_hist NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT f.id_hist
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
)
UNION
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, g.new_price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a `left join`?

```
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto,
       COALESCE(g.price, f.price) as price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f LEFT JOIN
     new_table g 
     ON f.id_new = g.id_hist;
```