# Filter a value from two table after merge both

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

First: say that this post is related to [**url**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393804/how-to-merge-two-tables-to-get-the-last-new-rows-from-table-2-and-the-rest-from)

Second: If you see the next image: [image]

I want to filter for one id. is simple if i go to table 2 and look into my record using id, but the problem is, i need some information from table 1 that i don't have into table 2

To show this into a form.

Third: If my table 2 is empty, when i filter by the 654 id, my query must take all the information from table 1

So i don't have no idea how start...  can somebody help me again?
i tried this:

```
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, f.price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
WHERE f.id_hist IN
(SELECT DISTINCT f.id_hist
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
    where f.id_new = 654
)
UNION
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, g.new_price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
    inner join new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
where f.id_new = 654
```

but this code returns two records, with values 40 and 25

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a left join with a coalesce function (it gets the value of the first value and if it is null, then it gets the second value)

```
SELECT f.id_hist, f.producto, f.place, COALESCE(g.price,f.price) as price
FROM TABLE(fnc_historical('JAP')) f
LEFT JOIN new_table g on (f.id_new = g.id_hist)
WHERE f.id_hist = 654
```

Comment: Just wanted to post the same, perhaps it's better to select `WHEN g.id_hist IS NULL THEN f.price ELSE g.price END` so you make sure to take null values of the history table if there is a fitting datarow, but that depends on the details of the task and might not even matter...